# Salesforce REST API Integration Issue with Dynamic Path Parameter

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am currently working on integrating Salesforce with an external REST API.
The external API expects a URL in the format:

```
 https://message.com/api/v1/campaign/message/:botId
```

where:botId is a dynamic path parameter.

-I have tried to construct the URL using Apex, but it seems that Salesforce Apex REST annotations do not support this specific URL parameter style with:botId.

Here's the relevant part of my Apex code:

```
String baseUrl = 'https://message.com/api/v1/campaign/message/';
String botId = '123456789';
String endpoint = baseUrl + ':botId=' + botId;
String method = 'POST';

Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
headers.put('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

The external API expects the URL to include `/:botId`.

How can I format the URL correctly to match the API's requirements using Salesforce Apex? Is there an alternative approach or workaround that I can use?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: did you try URLEncoding the value of `endpoint` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no sure exactly how the REST API is set up, but most likely the :botId needs to be replaced, not set as a variable.

```
String baseUrl = 'https://message.com/api/v1/campaign/message/';
String botId = '123456789';
String endpoint = baseUrl + botId;
String method = 'POST';
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!